# Hibernate one-to-one mapping based on a many-to-one relationship with a MAX(date) applied

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a mapped `Message` object which has a parent-child relationship with itself. So each `Message` holds a `Set<Message> comments`. Besides the comments I would like to setup a one-to-one relationship with the last comment made so that I can use the last comment in my `Criteria`. In SQL I establish this like follows (no comment can have the same postDate so this does not result in double matches for me):

```
SELECT 
    parentM.*, 
    lastComment.* 
FROM 
    messages parentM 
    left outer join messages lastComment ON 
        lastComment.parentId=parentM.messageId AND 
        lastComment.postDate=(SELECT MAX(subM.postDate) FROM messages subM WHERE subM.parentId = parentM.messageId);
```

Now I would like to know how to set this up in a Hibernate xml mapping but am unsure how to use the formula property or if I should be using a different mechanism. I hoped the following would work but it does not.

```
<one-to-one name="latestComment"  
    class="Message"  
    cascade="none"
    property-ref="parent"
    formula="postDate=(MAX(allComments.postDate) FROM messages allComments WHERE allComments.parentId=id)" 
    lazy="proxy">
</one-to-one>
```

With this mapping I get the result I want as long as there is only one comment. But the forumla is completely ignored. The examples I have seem all use simple formula's just mapping on a different column, not using a subquery.

Looking forward to some pointers

Comment: `formula` is for specifying an other value than parent primary key for matching the child key/property-ref. You can not filters among candidate children through formula. It does not look like `one-to-one` supports an attribute for this currently. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be *totally* wrong here (please excuse me if I am), but I can't help feeling that the scenario you are trying to handle may be better served by a triggered procedure on the database. Let the database engine itself handle updating the pointer to the "most recent" comment. That way you don't have a potentially expensive MAX function - you just look at the postDate for that comment.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for your reply. You might end up being right. I do really like the option to be dbms independent. And unless I'm unaware of a way of hibernate setting up triggers, I would need to tie myself into a specific dbms or maintain multiple build scripts.

Comment: Ah, these are the interceptors and events. Not quite sure why I didn't think of that before. I am still interested in the actual answer to my question so I'll leave it open for a little while longer. For now you have already pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: hibernate events is how I will proceed on this. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to suggest something that helped.

Answer (score 1):

formula is a SQL expression, not HQL, so your formula as expressed won't work.

What I do in these situations is iterate through the collection to find the desired target entity. Otherwise you're increasing the complexity of the queries to hydrate the object for no real value.

You're already fetching the most recent comment, why force it to be fetched twice?

Comment: Ah, I'll have a go at plain sql instead of HQL. Thanks. In my case I do not want to iterate over the results as my goal is to use values of the most recent comment in my parent Message query. This could potentially lead to very expensive java looping processes where SQL is made to optimize this. My comments are loaded lazily so I would only fetch it twice if I indeed print the comments to my page.